# NodeJs Firebase functions - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://google.com

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-contacts-api, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use google contact api in firebase free plan. It gives me an error ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND www.google.com www.google.com:443

As far as I know firebase allow us to user google services in their free plan but why I am getting this error.

```
var options = {
          host: 'www.google.com',
          path: '/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=token&alt=json'
        };

https.get(options, function(res) {
//my function
});
```

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code?

Comment: Running it through firebase cloud functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With spark plan of firebase, there is a restriction on domains and you can't call any API other than Google.

For your case, you should replace `www.google.com` with `www.googleapis.com` to get it work

Answer (score 0):

Username in the URL should be `default`, not `me`.